# Python emailer not working

Tags: python, smtplib

I am trying to write a Python class that will send emails using Python's `smtplib` libraries. I got it to work with standard Gmail, but am having trouble getting the config to work with other accounts.

Emailer Class config and send method:

```
def configure(self,  serverLogin, serverPassword, fromAddr, toAddr, serverHost='mail.myserver.edu', serverPort=465):
    self.server=smtplib.SMTP(serverHost,serverPort) #set the server host/port - currently configured for gmail
    self.server.ehlo()
    self.server.starttls()
    self.server.ehlo()
    self.server.login(serverLogin, serverPassword)  #login to senders email
    self.fromAddr = fromAddr
    self.toAddr = toAddr

def send(self):
    msgText = email.MIMEText.MIMEText("\n".join(self.message))
    self.msg.attach(msgText) 
    print "Sending email to %s " % self.toAddr
    text = self.msg.as_string() #conver the message contents to string format
    self.server.sendmail(self.fromAddr, self.toAddr, text)  #send the email
```

Emailer Test method:

```
def test(self):
    message = "Like a boss"  #body message of the email
    attachment = ["/Desktop/testImage2"]    #list of attachments
    image = ["/Desktop/testImage2"]
    emailer = Emailer() 
    emailer.addAttachment(attachment)
    emailer.addToMessage(message,image)
    emailer.setSubject("Python Test")
    emailer.configure(serverLogin="loginname", serverPassword="password", fromAddr="myaddr@myserver.edu", toAddr=["otheraddr@gmail.com"])
    emailer.send()
```

I set up my email account successfully in other mail clients (like Outlook) using this information, and the classes work just fine when I use `serverHost = 'smtp.gmail.com'` and `serverPort = 587`.  However, when I run the `test()` class in the terminal with my non-Gmail server information, the code appears to hang on this bit:

```
/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/smtplib.pyc in __init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout)
254         self.esmtp_features = {}
255         if host:
--> 256             (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
257             if code != 220:
258                 raise SMTPConnectError(code, msg)

/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/smtplib.pyc in connect(self, host, port)
315             print>>stderr, 'connect:', (host, port)
316         self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
--> 317         (code, msg) = self.getreply()
318         if self.debuglevel > 0:
319             print>>stderr, "connect:", msg

/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/smtplib.pyc in getreply(self)
359         while 1:
360             try:
--> 361                 line = self.file.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
362             except socket.error as e:
363                 self.close()

/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/socket.pyc in readline(self, size)
474             while True:
475                 try:
--> 476                     data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
477                 except error, e:
478                     if e.args[0] == EINTR:

KeyboardInterrupt:
```

Can anyone tell me why it's getting stuck here?

Comment: What's the actual exception message you're getting?

Comment: I'm not getting a message because I have to `control+c` out of it every time.  It appears to get stuck in an infinite loop there.

Comment: Can you post more of the Emailer class?  particularly the `send()` function?

Comment: What do you mean by you are having problems with other account? other than gmail? other mailing services like yahoo, hotmail etc?

Comment: @1.618 Edited the question to include more of the code.

Comment: @ShivaShinde I have my own server (it's not through an emailing service like Gmail)

Comment: Can you post the stack trace at the point that your program hangs? All we can tell is that it's waiting for some data from the network which never arrives, but we don't know what it's waiting for. You could also set the debuglevel of your smtp object to nonzero in order to see the SMTP exchange as it happens.

Comment: @WimLewis That's all I have.  I have to force exit otherwise it will run forever (and that's the print out I get when I `control+c` it) and the error occurs in the python library so I'm not sure how to do a stack trace on it.

Comment: I don't see a line in your `while true:` loop that would make it break out of the loop.

Comment: @jcfollower that's not my code.  That's part of the python smtplib code I'm using (which works fine when configured using Gmail or other standard email services)

Comment: can you put the line where you're calling `self.server.sendmail` inside a try/catch block?

Comment: @1.618 I tried that and it didn't work.  I think because it's not actually erroring on anything, just infinitely waiting.

Comment: @kdubs How did you get the information on what line the program freezees?

Comment: @NiklasR I `control+C` out and ipython printed that.

Comment: How long are you waiting before hitting Ctrl-C?  If you use `STMP.set_debuglevel(True)`, you'll get a lot of status messages as the client communicates with the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it turns out the problem was that I needed to be using `SMTP_SSL` instead of just `SMTP` because of the security settings on my server.

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe is connection problem. Check the access using telnet and check the server answer.

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587

Trying 64.233.186.109...
Connected to smtp.gmail.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP f103sm809119qkh.38 - gsmtp
```

Comment: Will this work for a non-gmail server?  The server I'm using is a private one and not through an email service.

Comment: ahh ok sorry but, try test a telnet connect in your server mail.myserver.edu and port 465 from this server. I'm changing my answer.

Comment: when I ran `telnet myserver.edu 465` I got the `Connected to myserver.edu` response.

Answer (score 0):

Try the telnet test for you server, the python error described is connection problem. Try `telnet mail.myserver.edu 465` for example.